# ¿Cómo poner una versión a mi apk en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Cuándo una aplicación ya está instalada en Android y ves la información de la aplicación aparece la versión que se tiene instalada. 
En Android Studio todas las aplicaciones tienen por defecto **versión 1.0**  y yo quiero ir modificando esa versión.

Comment: Esto lo haces a través de Gradle, así como te lo comenta @Jorgesys. Debes tener en cuenta que si vas a publicar el App a la tienda y deseas luego publicar actualizaciones de ella, estas versiones deben ser modificadas por una mayor, de esa forma no presentarás inconsistencias con el control de versiones del App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml` pero ahora es recomendable realizarlo dentro del `build.gradle` por medio de **versionName** (esto sobreescribe lo definido dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`).

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
  }
 ...
 ...
}
```

> **versionName** : Cadena utilizada como número de versión que se muestra a
>   los usuarios. Esta configuración se puede especificar como una cadena
>   sin formato o como una referencia a un recurso de cadena.

---

Es importante comentar que cuando subes una nueva versión a Google Play Store necesitas cambiar el `versionCode`.

> **versionCode** Un número entero utilizado como número de versión interno. Este número sólo se utiliza para determinar si una versión es
>   más reciente que otra, con números más altos que indican versiones más
>   recientes. Este no es el número de versión que se muestra a los
>   usuarios.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html